# Separate geom_bracket for each facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add `geom_bracket` to show significant differences in a few boxplots shown in a `facet_wrap`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is an example using the iris dataset.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

data <- iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Species)

ggplot(data, aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ Species) +
  geom_bracket(
    xmin = c("Petal.Length"), xmax = c("Sepal.Length"), y.position = c(7.5),
    label = c("*")
  )
```

This gives a graph like this:
[image]

As you can see, the brackets go above all three plots. How can I specify the `geom_bracket` separately for each of the three graphs?

(E.g. have a bracket over Petal.Length to Sepal.Length in setosa, no brackets in versicolor, and 2 brackets in virginica)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need one `geom_bracket` per bracket, and `subset` your data frame according to your facet variable, so that each facet can have its own bracket.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

data <- iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Species)

ggplot(data, aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ Species) +
  geom_bracket(data = subset(data, Species == "setosa"),
               xmin = "Petal.Length", xmax = "Sepal.Length", y.position = 7.5,
               label = "*") +
  geom_bracket(data = subset(data, Species == "virginica"),
               xmin = "Petal.Length", xmax = "Sepal.Length", y.position = 7.5,
               label = "*") +
  geom_bracket(data = subset(data, Species == "virginica"),
               xmin = "Petal.Width", xmax = "Sepal.Width", y.position = 8.5,
               label = "*")
```

[image]